# A distribution-like numerical sequence and a problem regarding a limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, probability-theory, probability-distributions

There is a sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq 1} \subset [0, \infty)$ such that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty x_n = 1$. One has to prove that
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left( 1- \left(1-x_k\right)^n \right) = 0. $$

The conditions $x_n \geq 0 $ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty x_n = 1$ might suggest that $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is some kind of probability distribution (since $x_n \leq 1$ must also hold), but I don't know whether it helps.

I tried to use Bernoulli's inequality this way: $x_n \leq 1 $ so $-x_n \geq -1$, so we have
$$ \left( 1-x_k \right)^n \geq 1+n(-x_k) = 1-nx_k $$
Using this, we may write:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left( 1- \left( 1-x_k \right)^n \right) \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left( 1- \left( 1-nx_k\right) \right) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} nx_k = n \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_k = n $$
Therefore
$$ \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left( 1- \left(1-x_k\right)^n \right) \leq 1, $$
but it seems pretty useless in regard of our problem...

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(1-(1-x_k)^n\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor}\left(1-(1-x_k)^n\right)+\sum_{k>\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor}\left(1-(1-x_k)^n\right).$$
As you observed, we have $0\le1-(1-x_k)^n\le nx_k$, so
$$\frac1n\sum_{k>\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor}\left(1-(1-x_k)^n\right)\le\sum_{k>\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor}x_k\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$
because the series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty x_k$ converges. Now
$$\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor}\left(1-(1-x_k)^n\right)\le\frac{\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor}n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0.$$

Comment: Nice approach. I'll point out for pedagogical purposes that you really just need any cutoff that is goes to infinity but remains $o(n)$; there was nothing special about $\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Nice proof indeed, thank you. I am wondering if it can be solved using probabilistic methods...